# Como fazer um programa em R que forneça o resultado abaixo?

Tags: r

Estou com uma dúvida em relação para fazer um algoritmo que forneça o resultado da equação abaixo. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A equação da pergunta pode ser programada do seguinte modo.

```
media_amos <- function(z, na.rm = TRUE){
  if(na.rm) z[is.na(z)] <- 0
  n <- nrow(z)
  cmb <- choose(n, 2)
  z[row(z) == col(z)] <- 0
  sum(z)/(2*cmb)
}

x <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6)

media_amos(x)
#[1] 18.5

mean(x)
#[1] 18.5
```

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo.